# how can i using icon-user & icon-lock bootstrap css framwork in a form that in textfield to show the icon

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

im using bootstrap css i need to put icon-user and icon-lock on login form but doesn't appear i need u sre help to solve this problems
below is my code

```
<div class=" container">
<div class="hero-unit clearfix">
<div class="pull-right">
  <form class="well">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="span3 icon-user" placeholder="Type your username">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="span3 icon-lock" placeholder="Type your password">
  <label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Log me in</button>
 </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
<div class=" container">
<div class="hero-unit clearfix">
<div class="pull-right">
   <form class="well">
      <label>Username</label>
      <div class="input-prepend">
         <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Type your username">
      </div>
      <label>Password</label>
      <div class="input-prepend">
         <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
         <input type="password" placeholder="Type your password">
      </div>
      <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Log me in</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i try it but still doesn't work but the it apear the box to put the icon but empty

Comment: Do you have the `glyphicons-halflings.png` file?